# How to mutate a column based on values occurring in a particular sequence?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, dplyr

I have a data frame `df`.

```
  df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),  process = c("inspection", "evaluation", "result","inspection", "result", "evaluation", "result", "inspection","result","evaluation","result","result","evaluation"))
```

I need to insert a column `true_process` such that if `evaluation` comes before the `result` for a particular `ID`, then it is `true`. If it comes after or if it is missing, it should take the value `false`.

The code that I have tried.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(true_process = case_when(
        !any(process == "evaluation") ~ "False",
        length(process == "evaluation")[[1]] > length(process == "result")[[1]] ~ "False",
        TRUE ~ "True"
    )) 
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
      ID process    true_process
   <dbl> <fct>      <chr>       
 1     1 inspection True        
 2     1 evaluation True        
 3     1 result     True        
 4     2 inspection True        
 5     2 result     True        
 6     2 evaluation True        
 7     3 result     False       
 8     3 inspection False       
 9     3 result     False       
10     4 evaluation True        
11     4 result     True        
12     4 result     True        
13     4 evaluation True
```

The expected output is as follows

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
      ID process    true_process
   <dbl> <fct>      <lgl>       
 1     1 inspection TRUE        
 2     1 evaluation TRUE        
 3     1 result     TRUE        
 4     2 inspection FALSE       
 5     2 result     FALSE       
 6     2 evaluation FALSE       
 7     3 result     FALSE       
 8     3 inspection FALSE       
 9     3 result     FALSE       
10     4 evaluation FALSE       
11     4 result     FALSE       
12     4 result     FALSE       
13     4 evaluation FALSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your updated data, you can check if the index of the last instance of `evaluation` is less than any of the indices of `result`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(true_process = any(tail(which(process == "evaluation"), 1) < which(process == "result")))


# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
      ID process    true_process
   <dbl> <chr>      <lgl>       
 1     1 inspection TRUE        
 2     1 evaluation TRUE        
 3     1 result     TRUE        
 4     2 inspection FALSE       
 5     2 result     FALSE       
 6     2 evaluation FALSE       
 7     3 result     FALSE       
 8     3 inspection FALSE       
 9     3 result     FALSE       
10     4 evaluation FALSE       
11     4 result     FALSE       
12     4 result     FALSE       
13     4 evaluation FALSE
```

Comment: This does work on the test data, but if you try with `df[-2, ]` so there is just an inspection followed by a result without an evaluation, then you get TRUE which I don't think is desired based on the text description. Of course, I'm not sure if that could ever happen. Maybe just add in an `any(process == "evaluation")`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But my actual df looks something like this. `df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),  process = c("inspection", "evaluation", "result","inspection", "result", "evaluation", "result", "inspection","result","evaluation","result","result","evaluation"))` . In this df the output for true_process when ID==4 column should return FALSE because result has come before evaluation. But your code is returning True. How can this be achieved?

Comment: @Silent_bliss - see updated answer.  You should also edit the new example data into the question above.